# How to override arrays with the same name in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have create `foo` function:

```
function foo(json) {
    var i = 0;
    var array= [];
    for(i=0;i<30;i++){
        var tmp = json[i].unique;
        array.push(tmp);
    }
}
```

Every time I invoke `foo` function with a different JSON it creates an array and keeps the last one.

how can I override this array each time I invoke `foo` function?
Thank you!

## *** Update ***

I declared `var array = []` on the top of my js file as a different variable, and I tried to use `var array` variable that belongs to the `foo` function outside of his scope, **it was a beginners' mistake** unfortunately :|

Comment: why? how does it help?

Comment: `for(i=0;i<29;z++)` z++? ar u sure?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "keep the last one" - if you call foo 3x then, within each of those calls, you get a different array and when foo finishes, `array` goes out of scope and you don't have it anymore.  Unless you have some other code that you're not showing us.  Are you saying you want to keep `array` outside of `foo` ?

Comment: You code works well, could not find issue Check http://jsfiddle.net/szswbmx9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `array` globally and make it empty every time you call `foo`

```
var array= []; // global

function foo(json) {
  var i = 0;
  array = []; // empty array before executing for loop
  for(i=0;i<29;i++){
    var tmp = json[i].unique; //some of my json a parameter.  
    array.push(tmp); //push data to array
   }
```

Comment: The problem is with `json` array, not with the array `array`. OP is using `array` locally, which is better

Comment: it creates the array x times with the same values :/ i still have it for more then 1. i am still trying :)

Comment: How does it makes any difference here? declaring empty globally and re-declaring again?

Comment: I am not re-declaring, see code carefully, I am making that array empty

Comment: @AdiAzarya  access array after calling function foo you will always get last updated array values

Comment: Yes it works but it may be problematic for OP if he wants to retain and reuse array value..

Comment: I think people should consider adding comment before downvoting